# Qt PDF take screenshot of part of file

Tags: qt, pdf

I am using Qt PDF module to open a PDF file. How can I take a screenshot of part of the file and save it?

Answer (score 0):

Since I guess this is impossible, I will convert the PDF to a image using pdf2image and work with images